# Is git required when working with elastic beanstalk?

Tags: django, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to learn how to use elastic beanstalk for django and have so far gone off these tutorials:

[Real Python Blog Tutorial](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/)

[AWS Documentation Tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html)

The AWS tutorial creates an elastic beanstalk environment and updates it without using a git repository at all. Although the AWS tutorial does not cover setting up an RDS database on AWS, I'd like to accomplish what the AWS tutorial does and additionally set up a mysql database for my django app.

Can I do so without a git repository?

Any suggestions as to how I can get this done?

I've been struggling with trying to connect my app to a database for sometime now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs the EB CLI doesn't require git. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact . It states "If git is installed..." So its optional.

The EB Console also allows you to upload a zip file as well. See screenshot. 
[image: Upload and Deploy]

Even though this is possible. You really should just use git, especially if you are not using a version control system in its stead.

Comment: Thanks for your response George. Please excuse the newbie question, but what is the benefit of using a git repo as oppose to just deploying straight from EB CLI?

Comment: Its a best practice.  Git and other version control systems are vital.  Here is a related doc that might give you more reasons: stackoverflow.com/questions/1408450/why-should-i-use-version-control